# MySQL Calculate Percentage

Tags: mysql, percentage

I have a MySQL database with 4 items: `id` (numerical), `group_name`, `employees`, and `surveys`.

In my `SELECT` I need to calculate the percentage of 'employees' who, by the number in 'surveys', have taken the survey.

This is the statement I have now:

```
SELECT
  group_name,
  employees,
  surveys,
  COUNT( surveys ) AS test1, 
  ((COUNT( * ) / ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM a_test)) * 100 ) AS percentage
FROM
  a_test
GROUP BY
  employees
```

Here is the table as it stands:

```
INSERT INTO a_test (id, group_name, employees, surveys) VALUES
(1, 'Awesome Group A', '100', '0'),
(2, 'Awesome Group B', '200', '190'),
(3, 'Awesome Group C', '300', '290');
```

I would love to calculate the percentage of `employees` who by the number in `surveys` have taken the survey. i.e. as shown in the data above, the `Awesome Group A` would be 0% and `Awesome Group B` would be 95%.

Comment: This `GROUP BY` practice should not be used. It is non-standard and will produce undesired results.

Comment: sample data and your wished reslut maybe ?

Comment: Here is the table as it stands:   'INSERT INTO `a_test` (`id`, `group_name`, `employees`, `surveys`) VALUES
(1, 'Awesome Group A', '100', '0'),
(2, 'Awesome Group B', '200', '190'),
(3, 'Awesome Group C', '300', '290');'   I would love to calulate the percentage of 'employees' who by the number in 'surveys' have taken the survey.    IE like above the Awesome Group A would be 0% and Awesome Group B would be 95%

Comment: Please note that you can edit the question to add new details. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: @Kermit Why is GROUP BY bad?

Comment: @Thomas [MySQL chooses which fields to `GROUP BY` as it feels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html). All other platforms require that non-aggregated fields in the `SELECT` appear in the `GROUP BY`. MySQL doesn't follow this standard.

Comment: @Thomas Just to add that it isn't the fields that it chooses as it feels, it's the value for the non-group fields which it chooses to display.  In 5.8 (maybe 5.7 too) the behaviour is now consistent with other databases.  The non-standard behaviour was useful but dangerous if you were relying on it.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

try this

```
   SELECT group_name, employees, surveys, COUNT( surveys ) AS test1, 
        concat(round(( surveys/employees * 100 ),2),'%') AS percentage
    FROM a_test
    GROUP BY employees
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0761/5)

Comment: How can I use the column alias here? Like if I am calculating the employees value like "employees_type1+employees_type2 AS employees, then is it possible that I can use the employees alias there in the concat function ?

Comment: No you cant. you have to use the join or subquery.