# Mysql : percentage mysql inside listview vb net

Tags: mysql, percentage

I calculate a percentage, it did work with mysql query,

```
+----------+
| %        |
+----------+
| 20.00%   |  
| 16.67%   |  
| 50.00%   |   
+----------+
```

But when  want to read it inside listview vb net, it won't show up like in mysql query

```
+----------+
| %        |
+----------+
| 20.0000  |  
| 16.6777  |  
| 50.0000  |   
+----------+
```

How to read inside list view exactly same with mysql query,

Thanks master, sorry my English is so bad :(

Edit : 
I took example query form this : [calculate percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746749/mysql-calculate-percentage)

Query :

```
SELECT group_name, employees, surveys, COUNT( surveys ) AS test1, 
        concat(round(( surveys/employees * 100 ),2),'%') AS percentage
    FROM a_test
    GROUP BY employees
```

Comment: Can you please share the query you're using?

Comment: problem solved, i don't know how it works, but i restarted my pc n it's good now. thanks .:)