# How to calculating percentages in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to calculate named "Success Rate" with this 2 query in one table.

The First is

```
SELECT sum(`session count`) as success 
FROM itsqm_trubex._d_itqsm_tmenu 
where `statusCode` in ('00000000', '00008006');
```

The Second is

```
SELECT sum(`session count`) as total FROM itsqm_trubex._d_itqsm_tmenu;
```

How to write query if i want the result is `(success / total) * 100%`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746749/mysql-calculate-percentage

Comment: `SELECT SUM(SESSION COUNT) AS total,(SELECT 
 SUM(SESSION COUNT) AS success FROM itsqm_trubex._d_itqsm_tmenu WHERE statusCode IN ('00000000', '00008006')) AS success,((SELECT SUM(SESSION COUNT) AS success FROM itsqm_trubex._d_itqsm_tmenu WHERE statusCode IN ('00000000', '00008006')/SUM(SESSION COUNT))*100 AS Percentage FROM itsqm_trubex._d_itqsm_tmenu;`

Comment: @Aishwarya: That is not a comment, but an attempt at an answer. Please post it as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: i am not getting any answer tab here . so, i commented here